# How to add the correct admob or adview dependency to an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, admob

I'm developing an app and I want to add an admob banner add to it. I asked the permissions in the manifest file for Internet and for the network state. Then I added the dependency for admob. After entering the dependency to the gradle file, the app in my phone app crashes during testing.

It happens when I add the dependency. I want to find the correct dependency or some how fix this if this happens because of another reason.

Here are the dependencies I added:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Needs more details. Can you share the error trace log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below **Meta tag** inside of Aplication in your **Manifest**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    //Add this
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_app_id" /> //Add here your admob app id

    ...

</application>
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add 2 meta-data tags inside the manifest xml of your application.

```
<application>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" /> // put your admob app id in quotes

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Hope this helps